WHy did my token just suddently dissapear out of my wallet?
The token disappeared and I asked the Phantom wallet AI for help, and it told me to check the token list, and it was not even there, is there anyways to see where the token has gone. where it is in my account, and if there's any way to get it back to show back into my account?
